# BigQuery Table Wildcard Function Aliases?

Tags: google-bigquery

According to documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from), I should be able to reference a table wildcard function as an alias:

```
...
FROM
  [project_name:]datasetId.tableId |
  (subselect_clause) |
  table wildcard function
[[AS] alias]
...
```

But, when I try to do this, things fail:

```
bq query "SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(my_data, \"TIMESTAMP(table_id) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2014-05-21') AND TIMESTAMP('2014-06-10')\") AS blah WHERE blah.foo = 5 LIMIT 30"
Waiting on bqjob_some_id ... (0s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job 'some_id': Field 'blah.foo' not found in table 'mydata.20140521'; did you mean 'foo2'?
```

I want to do a join on the data returned from the wildcard function treating it as a single table, so aliasing it is very important to me. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you linked to does mention "Do not use alias with a table wildcard function."

You might want to try

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(--insert query here--)) AS blah 
WHERE blah.foo = 5 LIMIT 30"
```

Comment: If by "clearly" you mean "as a footnote contradicting the huge FROM syntax above it, then yes. Anyway, thanks for the answer. It's what I wound up doing, but makes my SQL look really ugly.

Comment: I wasn't trying to condescend. Sorry it it sounded that way. I've edited the post.

Comment: No worries. I've just been running into a lot of unintuitive behavior from BigQuery, so I'm already annoyed by the whole thing. Anyway, thanks again for the answer.